# What are my options if my question receives no answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions

Several days ago I posted a question. I got no answers at all, so people probably just didn't look at the post. My question remains however, and I'm still looking for help. Since it's been a few days and the question is no longer on the list of questions, I thought I could ask the question again. I framed the question slightly differently and explained more specifically what I was after.

The only response I have gotten is someone flagging it as a repeat question. Which, yes, it is, but I thought the point of that was that I could look at the question I was repeating to get my answer. Since the other question has no answers, the fact that it's a repeat doesn't seem like it should matter.

So if I can't ask a question a second time, what am I supposed to do to get information?

Comment: Don't ever duplicate your question, tag it properly, and if it's too specific or hard, place a bounty. If you don't get answers then you simply won't

Comment: Looking at the question that probably lead to this post, I immediately notice the low number of views: 9. And that's probably including me. Add some more relevant tags - the single one you used is quite obscure. Also, what *programming* question is beyond it? "Someone elsewhere suggested using the ZMQ blocks, however, when I tried .." suggests you have some inkling of a specific programming language and code.

Answer (score 3):

Two options you can start with:

- Go back and edit your original question, improve it with some more information or a more concise example of what you are trying to achieve - look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
- Place a bounty on your question

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers). You should definitely **not** repost the question, but you can edit it - this will bump the question. You shouldn't do this only for this purpose, that's considered abuse, but try to improve your question to make it more attractive. Maybe you can share some research you have done in the meantime?

If that fails, your only option is to place a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), but you'll need to accumulate some reputation first before that comes an option.

Comment: On bounties: or have a question interesting enough for someone else with rep to spare.

Comment: Zephyr does not have enough rep to offer a bounty.