# I added three questions and my questions are not answered?

Tags: discussion

I have added already 3 questions, and none of them are viewed to the readers. Every time I get a response from your editor, I adjust it and correct the editors notes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow. Please see how to ask a question for your other questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I looked at your previous questions. They are visible, however if no one knows the answer, then they won't be answered. It is not a guarantee that questions will be answered when posted on here.

Comment: Hello Aneta, This is depend on users ,  if a user is friendly with your Question then he/she will answer but if user don't have information or knowledge about the question then, it can take some time to answer. You don't worry, someone will answer you correct. Please be patience, patience is a Virtue

Comment: You have asked 5 questions in total, not counting this one (which was incorrectly posted on the main site, then migrated here to Meta). Of those 5, your first 3 are closed and deleted. The most recent 2 are still visible. The full list is: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611754), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076188), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64974136), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65026411), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65111470)

Comment: Related: [What is the best way to get response for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256658/11682469)

Comment: From the help-center: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Some more similar questions here on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329476/what-are-my-options-if-my-question-receives-no-answers ; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261078/what-do-i-do-if-my-question-has-received-no-answers-or-comments ; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265233/what-should-you-do-if-nobody-answers-your-question-can-you-repost-it ; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303634/what-is-the-accepted-method-of-renewing-interest-in-a-question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this question [Can I display more than one chart on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65026411) you've included a script.js file but that is not going to work as viewers don't have that script.js file. You need to include it in the snippet because that script.js contains the reason why your chart doesn't work.

In this question [Is it possible to keep the port view and container automatically adjusting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65111470) I doubt if what you want to achieve is possible with only CSS. If that is the case (I'm not an CSS expert at all) then it is unlikely you'll get an answer. It might help if you indicate if a solution with JavaScript can work for you, if it is indeed impossible to solve with CSS.

Your questions are tagged correctly, have a well written title and are complete. Some nitpick might say the code/Markdown is not minimal, but that is about it. I'm not sure if there are related / similar questions that you looked at, but they didn't solve your problem. It might help if you include links to those and explain why those other questions didn't help.

Your questions got 18 and 30 views. In the heavy traffic tags that isn't too bad, but you need to stumble on just the right person that has some spare minutes left to produce an answer for you. While SO is a popular site it still is volunteer labor without service level agreements. Give it [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) to receive an answer.